# Invert Axis directions

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I'm trying to invert the direction of the y-axis.

I want to have 2 y-axis : the first going up (as usual) and the second, starting from 0 and going down (to 5)...

Here's what I do :

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=0.8cm}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1.5, -7)(21,7)
        \psaxes[comma,Dx=2.5,                                   % this y-axis goes up
            arrowscale=1.5]{->}(19, 6)[Distance (m),0][Distance,0]
        \pscurve[showpoints=true](0, 0)(3, 2)(5, 3)(7.5, 5)(10, 5)(15, 3)
                (18, 0)
                (15, -3)(10, -5)(7.5, -5)(5, -3)(3, -2)(0, 0)
        \psaxes[xAxis=false, yStep=-1]{->}(0,-5)                % and this goes down
    \end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

Her's what I obtain : 
[image: What I obtain]
 But I can't make the numbering increase as it goes down...

I tried `Oy=5` but I didn't worked, and I tried also `yStep=-1`, but the minus is simply ignored, I think...

I'd like to have the axis be like this :

```
  ^
  |
1 |
  |
0 +--|---|------------- >
  |  1   2
1 |
  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the second one use:

```
    \psaxes[xAxis=false,ylabelPos=left,dy=-1,showorigin=false]{->}(-10,-6)
```

To understand what happens, run:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
 \psaxes{->}(5,5)
 \psaxes[linecolor=red]{->}(-5,-5)
\end{pspicture} 

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
 \psaxes[dx=-1]{->}(5,5)
 \psaxes[linecolor=red,dx=-1,dy=-1]{->}(-5,-5)
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

You'll find *a lot*  of examples in the documentation of `pst-plot` and on http://PSTricks.tug.org

Comment: Can you just explain me the coordinates and the `showorigin` ? I'm afraid I don't fully understand...

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: `A picture says a thousand words`. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Herbert I don't see in pstricks-doc.pdf where this is mentioned?

Comment: it is the package `pst-plot` which supports axes plotting

Answer (score 0):

You can label the axes on your own with multido.

Code:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=0.8cm}
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1.5, -7)(21,7)
        \psaxes[comma,Dx=2.5,                                   % this y-axis goes up
            arrowscale=1.5]{->}(19, 6)[Distance (m),0][Distance,0]
        \pscurve[showpoints=true](0, 0)(3, 2)(5, 3)(7.5, 5)(10, 5)(15, 3)
                (18, 0)
                (15, -3)(10, -5)(7.5, -5)(5, -3)(3, -2)(0, 0)
        \psaxes[xAxis=false, yStep=-1,ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,-5)                % and this goes down
                \multido{\I=-1+-1,\n=1+1}{5}{\psline[linewidth=0.5pt](-0.2,\I)(0.2,\I)\rput(-0.5,\I){\n}}
    \end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```